# How to sign certificate by other certificate

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, certificate, x509certificate

I have two X509Certificate2 certificates. How to sign one certificate by another?

I will be very grateful for work sample.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic info is available at MSDN @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729856%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
You will need to use ClientCredentials and  ClientCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.

Answer (score 0):

A Certificate is already signed. You can sign a certificate request or sign a certificate you are creating (at "creation time"). 

To create a signed certificate  with C#, you can use the IX509CertificateRequestCertificate interface  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377124(v=vs.85).aspx). 
Use the "SignerCertificate" property (the signer certificate must be installed in a certificate store on your computer).

You have to add "CERTENROLLLib" to your C# project to access the IX509CertificateRequestCertificate interface.

Here is an example about using the IX509CertificateRequestCertificate interface   in C# : https://exceptionshub.com/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-c.html